# filtrado de una colección

Tags: mongodb

hola supongamos que tengo una `collection` llamada **xxx** en ella se encuentra un conjunto de documentos como lo siguientes:

```
{
    "mod":1,    
    "configuracion": {
        "corw":"5d1907bd5255a40c785c8d827",
         "modulos": [
            {
            "idModulo": 1,
            "mesa": { 
                "altura":"12cm",
                "anchura":"11cm"
             }
            },
            {
            "idModulo": 2,
            "silla": { 
                "altura":"12cm",
                "anchura":"11cm"
             }
            }
         ]
    }
}


{  
   "mod":2,
   "servicios":[  
      {  
         "nombre":"servicio 1",
         "costo":1234
      },
      {  
         "nombre":"servicio 2",
         "costo":1343
      }
   ]
}

{  
   "mod":3,
   "empreados":[  
      {  
         "nombre":"jose",
         "telefono":"12342222"
      },
      {  
         "nombre":"leonardo",
         "telefono":"134222223"
      }
   ]
}
```

este query me trae el documento con el elemento mod = 1

```
db.getCollection('xxx').find({mod:1})
```

pero quiero conseguir  de el elemento mod = 1 
donde idModulo = 1

o sea que filtre configuracion-->modulos-->idModulo = 1 y devuelva solo todo los elemento donde idModulo = 1 que a su vez seria lo mismo que decir que devuelva todos los elementos de modulos[0] como puedo realizar esta busqueda puesto que he intentado aplicando `{ modulos: { idModulo  : 1 } }` entre otras forma pero nada

Comment: Hola, ¿Podrías aclarar un poco el resultado que deseas obtener? Dices que deseas filtrar los documentos con `mod: 1` tales que tengan un elemento del `array` de `modulos` que tiene un campo `idModulo: "1"`. De eso entiendo que si un documento con valor `mod: 1` no contiene en el `array` de `modulos` un elemento con campo `idModulo: "1"`, el mismo no debe ser listado en el resultado. Por favor, corrígeme si me equivoco. Saludos

Comment: Hola, como estas me gustaria que la consulta me devolviera solo esto por ejemplo: {
            "idModulo": 1,
            "mesa": { 
                "altura":"12cm",
                "anchura":"11cm"
             }

Comment: y este es el query que llevo hasta ahora: db.xxx.aggregate([{$match:{mod:1}},{$unwind:"$configuracion"},{$unwind:"$configuracion.modulos"},{$project:{configuracion:"$configuracion.modulos"}}])    pero aun no obtengo lo que te dije antes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acuerdo a lo que dices en tu comentario, y según el modelo de documento que deseas consultar, puedes lograr la tarea usando un método de [agregación](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) como el siguiente:

(Suponiendo que tu colección se llama `modulos`):

```
db.modulos.aggregate([
  {$match: {mod: 1}},
  {$unwind: '$configuracion.modulos'},
  {$match: {'configuracion.modulos.idModulo': 1}},
  {$replaceRoot: {newRoot: '$configuracion.modulos'}}
]);
```

**EXPLICACIÓN**

El método de agregación aquí planteado supone realizar 4 etapas:

**Etapa [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/index.html):**

En esta etapa simplemente realizamos una búsqueda de documentos por el campo `mod`. Esta etapa nos devolverá todos los documentos cuyo campo `mod` sea igual a `1`.

**Etapa [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html):**

En esta etapa vamos a aplicar la operación de `$unwind` sobre el campo de tipo `Array` en la ruta `configuracion.modulos`. Esto producirá un documento por cada elemento de dicho `Array`.

**Segunda Etapa `$match`:**

En esta segunda etapa, vamos a filtrar los documentos obtenidos usando el campo `configuracion.modulos.idModulo`, de tal manera que sólo devolvemos aquellos cuyo valor `idModulo` es igual a `1`.

**Etapa [`$replaceRoot`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/index.html):**

En esta etapa vamos a reemplazar cada documento que hemos obtenido hasta ahora, por cada documento de la ruta `configuracion.modulos`. De esta forma sólo obtenemos dichos documentos al finalizar la agregación y el resultado final es el documento que estabas esperando:

> Todos los documentos de `configuracion.modulos` tales que `idModulo: 1`, para cada documento de la colección `modulos` donde `mod: 1`.

La salida del método anterior producirá una salida parecida a la siguiente:

```
{ "idModulo" : 1, "mesa" : { "altura" : "12cm", "anchura" : "11cm" } }
{ "idModulo" : 1, "ventana" : { "altura" : "12cm", "anchura" : "11cm" } }
{ "idModulo" : 1, "sofa" : { "altura" : "12cm", "anchura" : "11cm" } }
```

Para este ejemplo he creado 3 documentos de tipo `mod: 1`, en mi colección. Cada documento contiene en su campo `configuracion.modulos` al menos 1 documento con `idModulo: 1`.

Espero que esta sea la respuesta esperada y te ayude a resolver el problema.

Comment: Gracias Mauricio Contreras,  he probado y me ha funcionado y he aprendido algo nuevo. Feliz día.

Comment: Si la respuesta la consideras funcional, puedes marcarla como válida. ;) Saludos

Comment: disculpa la molestia si deseo hacer un update set a ese resultado  en mi caso solo hay un documento con idModulo" : 1 o sea lo de arriba esta bien me funciona perfecto pero a ese registro que me trae quiero aplicarle un update a ese resultado especifico. O sea quiero aplicar un update en la coleccion mod1 --> idModulo 1 que solo se modifique esa sesiona o sea el array en la posición x

Comment: Ok, para hacer un `update` sólo a ese documento lo harías de otra forma. El proceso de agregación no devuelve un documento que puedas salvar. Para eso debes realizar una `query`. Te invito a que realices otra pregunta indicando lo que has intentado y lo que deseas hacer, de esa forma se nutre mejor el sitio y quedan aclaradas ambas dudas. Saludos

Comment: Gracias, No tenia luz por eso no Respondí antes.

Comment: No hay problema, ¿por casualidad Venezuela?

Comment: Si, Barquisimeto (Venezuela)