# modificar(Update) A un elemento de un array

Tags: array, mongodb, sql

hola supongamos que tengo una collection llamada modulos en ella se encuentra un conjunto de documentos como lo siguientes:

```
{
    "mod":1,    
    "configuracion": {
        "corw":"5d1907bd5255a40c785c8d827",
         "modulos": [
            {
            "idModulo": 1,
            "mesa": { 
                "altura":"12cm",
                "anchura":"11cm"
             }
            },
            {
            "idModulo": 2,
            "silla": { 
                "altura":"12cm",
                "anchura":"11cm"
             }
            }
         ]
    }
}

{  
   "mod":2,
   "servicios":[  
      {  
         "nombre":"servicio 1",
         "costo":1234
      },
      {  
         "nombre":"servicio 2",
         "costo":1343
      }
   ]
}

{  
   "mod":3,
   "empreados":[  
      {  
         "nombre":"jose",
         "telefono":"12342222"
      },
      {  
         "nombre":"leonardo",
         "telefono":"134222223"
      }
   ]
}
```

Me gustaria Modificar(Update) solo un documento ejemplo:

```
{ "idModulo": 1, "mesa": { "altura":"12cm", "anchura":"11cm" }
```

por

```
{ "idModulo": 1, "mesa": { "altura":"133cm", "anchura":"112cm" }
```

Sin la necesidad de mandar a todo el documento o sea solo pasaría el valor:

```
{ "idModulo": 1, "mesa": { "altura":"133cm", "anchura":"112cm" }
```

antiriormente habia ralizado una pregunta de filtrado y quería aplicarla así

```
db.modulos.update(
    db.modulos.aggregate([
      {$match: {mod: 1}},
      {$unwind: '$configuracion.modulos'},
      {$match: {'configuracion.modulos.idModulo': 1}},
      {$replaceRoot: {newRoot: '$configuracion.modulos'}}
    ])
,
{
    $set: { "idModulo": 1, "mesa": { "altura":"133cm", "anchura":"112cm" }
})
```

también intente poner la consulta previa en una constante y pasarla como filtro en el update pero no da resultado y por lo que me han comentado en la duda anterior se debe realizar de otra manera. dejo el enlace de la duda anterior pues puede ser útil para otros visitantes. 
[filtrado-de-una-colección](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/279713/filtrado-de-una-colecci%C3%B3n)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/279713/filtrado-de-una-colecci%c3%b3n/280468#280468) anterior te di una forma de obtener un documento de un `Array` anidado. Ahora deseas realizar un `update` sobre dicho documento del `array`.

> **NOTA**: La solución aqui planteada funciona con MongoDB 3.6 o superior

Para lograrlo podemos usar el método [`update()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) o el método [`updateMany()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/) de MongoDB.

Una forma de hacerlo usando el método `update` sería la siguiente:

```
let docToUpdate = {
  idModulo: 1,
  mesa: {
    altura: "133cm",
    anchura: "112cm"
  }
}
try {
  db.modulos.update(
    {
      'mod': 1,
      'configuracion.modulos.idModulo': 1
    },
    {
      $set: {
        'configuracion.modulos.$[elem]': docToUpdate
      }
    },
    {
      multi: true,
      arrayFilters: [{'elem.idModulo': 1}]
    }
  );
} catch(error) {
  print(error);
}
```

Lo cual debe producir el siguiente resultado: (mi colección contiene 3 documentos que coinciden con el filtro, esto variará para tu colección)

> `WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 3, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 3 })`

Puedes notar además que he realizado la operación dentro de un bloque `try catch`, lo cual es bastante común cuando realizas operaciones sobre varios documentos a la vez.

**Explicación**

Lo primero que podemos observar en el código es que hemos definido una variable llamada `docToUpdate` que contiene efectivamente el nuevo documento que será sustituido (actualizado) en el `array`.

De acuerdo a la documentación del método `update`, el mismo recibe los siguientes parámetros:

**`query`**: En este caso la consulta para filtrar los documentos que deseamos actualizar:

```
{
  'mod': 1,
  'configuracion.modulos.idModulo': 1
}
```

Estamos indicándole a MongoDB que deseamos sólo los documentos cuyo campo `mod` sea igual a `1`, y que contenga dentro del `array` de `modulos` documentos con `idModulo` igual a `1` también.

**`update`**: El documento que indica la acción de actualización que realizaremos. En este caso vamos a establecer para cada documento encontrado por nuestra consulta, un valor para el elemento del `array` en el campo `configuracion.modulos`, cuyo campo `idModulo` sea igual a `1`.

Esto lo logramos usando el operador [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/#up._S_set), que nos permite especificar el campo (o los campos) que deseamos actualizar asignándoles un valor.

Dado que el campo `configuracion.modulos` es de tipo `array`, usaremos un identificador posicional ([`$[<identifier>]`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/#up._S_[%3Cidentifier%3E])) para referirnos a los elementos de nuestro `array`. Yo he escogido el nombre `elem`, puedes ponerle cualquier nombre válido. Lo ideal es escoger un nombre que tenga un sentido práctico con lo que estamos haciendo.

```
{
  $set: {
    'configuracion.modulos.$[elem]': docToUpdate // <= 'elem' es el identificador posicional de un elemento de nuestro array
  }
}
```

El valor que asignaremos al elemento del `array` es el documento almacenado en nuestra variable. (En este caso estamos reemplazando todo el documento en dicha posición)

**`multi`**: Este campo, cuando se establece a `true`, le indica al MongoDB que la actualización se realizará sobre todos los documentos que coincidan con el criterio de búsqueda. En caso contrario (el valor por defecto es `false`), sólo se actualizará un documento. Si la colección contiene más de un documento se actualizará el promero que se encuentre.

**`arrayFilters`**: Como su nombre lo indica, es un filtro que usaremos sobre un tipo `array`. Los filtros han de ser documentos pasados como elementos de `arrayFilters`, siendo éste un tipo `array`.

Cada elemento de `configuracion.modulos` ha sido identificado con el identificador posicional `elem`, por lo tanto, podemos acceder a los campos de cada documento usando la notación de punto, de la siguiente manera:

```
'elem.idModulo'
```

Nuestro filtro será:

```
{ 'elem.idModulo': 1 }
```

Lo cual le indica a MongoDB que la actualización se hará sobre el elemento del `array` en `configuracion.modulos`, cuyo valor de `idModulo` es igual a `1`.

Nuestro `arrayFilters` debería verse de la siguiente forma:

```
arrayFilters: [{'elem.idModulo': 1}] //<= arrayFilters es de tipo Array
```

De esta forma ya tenemos el documento, o los documentos actualizados con el valor que hemos definido en nuestra variable inicial.

Muestro las siguientes capturas de pantalla como ejemplo funcional de la solución aquí planteada:

Mostramos todos los documentos tales que `mod` es igual a `1`

```
db.modulos.find({mod: 1});
```

[image: Se muestran todos los documentos de la colección con <code>{'mod':1}</code>]

Ahora ejecutamos el proceso de `update`:

[image: Resultado de la ejecución del método <code>update</code>]

Claramente se observa que el proceso de actualización se realizó sobre 3 documentos. Que son efectivamente los únicos 3 documentos que coinciden con el parámetro de la consulta.

Mostramos los documentos modificados:

[image: Se muestran todos los documentos de la colección con <code>{'mod':1}</code> ya modificados]

Se observa en la imagen que los documentos han sido modificados con los nuevos valores.

Espero que esta respuesta te ayude a aclarar un poco el tema y sea la solución que necesitabas.

Comment: Buen día Gracias por la respuesta, y por la explicación, si me ha sido de utilidad. y gracias a ti he aprendido cosas nuevas. Una vez mas Gracias. y feliz día.